# Why does ArrayList.add() modify the object added?

Tags: java, arraylist

When I add an object to an ArrayList it gets chenged.

I am trying to make a java fx agenda app and so I need to pass an ArrayList with the objects I want in the table to an ObservableList.

The problem happens right in this function, at `tableToday.add(ret);`

```java
public ArrayList<SkEvent> getTableToday() {
        LocalDateTime clock = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(0,0));
        while (clock.until(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(23,59)), ChronoUnit.MINUTES)>0){
            System.out.println("clock: "+clock.toLocalTime().toString());

            SkEvent ret = new SkEvent(LocalDate.now(), clock.toLocalTime());

            if(existsEvent(clock)){
                System.out.println("Event exists.");

                ret = getEvent(clock);
                ret.setLocalDateTime(clock);
            }


            tableToday.add(ret);
            System.out.println("Added event "+ ret.getName() + " at "+ret.getTime().toString());
            LocalDateTime updatedClock = clock.plusMinutes(gap);
            clock = updatedClock;

        }
```

This is a part of the output:

```
clock: 21:00
Added event  at 21:00
clock: 21:30
Added event  at 21:30
clock: 22:00
Event exists.
Added event e at 22:00
clock: 22:30
Event exists.
Added event e at 22:30
clock: 23:00
Event exists.
Added event e at 23:00
clock: 23:30
Added event  at 23:30
Times in the table: 
21:00
21:30
23:00
23:00
23:00
23:30
```

As you can see I add 3 events at 22:00, 22:30 and 23:00, but outputing the event times on the ArrayList outputs 3 times the 23:00

It should output

```
Times in the table: 
21:00
21:30
22:00
22:30
23:00
23:30
```

Also, here is the `SkEvent` class:

```java
public class SkEvent{
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime time;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public SkEvent(LocalDate date, int hour, int minute, String name, String description) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = LocalTime.of(hour, minute);
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public SkEvent(LocalDate date, LocalTime time){
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.name = "";
        this.description = "";
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime(){
        return LocalDateTime.of(getDate(), getTime());
    }

    public SkEvent setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime){
        this.date = localDateTime.toLocalDate();
        this.time = localDateTime.toLocalTime();

        return this;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and the `getEvent()` method:

```java
private Map<SkEvent, LocalDateTime> actualEvents = new HashMap();
//(...)
    private SkEvent getEvent(LocalDateTime clock) {
        for(Map.Entry<SkEvent, LocalDateTime> entry: actualEvents.entrySet()){
            if(!entry.getKey().getLocalDateTime().isAfter(clock) && !entry.getValue().isBefore(clock)){
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Many thanks for the time.

Comment: `add` *doesn't* modify the objects. The most likely explanation is you're modifying the object yourself after adding it to the list.

Comment: How is the implementation of `SkEvent` look like?

Comment: you are modifying it in `if(existsEvent(clock)){` `add` isn't modifying it at all

Comment: It *obviously* happens because the 3 times in question enters the `if` block, as shown by the `Event exists.` output, **replacing** the `ret` value with a **single event** named `e`, as returned by the `getEvent(clock)` method. Look at the `getEvent` method to learn why. We certainly cannot tell you, since we can't see that code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I double checked your hypotesis, no I do not change the value after adding it. As you can see in my code I output the `LocalTime` of `ret` right before adding it and right after adding it iterate over the `ArrayList` to see it's values' `LocalTime`s. I mean the modification that happens when adding the object, not the one before it, because the object I try to add is what I want to add, as seen in the output. I'm now adding the code for the `SkEvent` class and ``getEvent()` method, I didn't think it would be necessary due to what I just explained. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try printing `ret` out _right_ before the add AND after the add?  I only see a print after, and a print way before.  Its doubtful the `add` is the problem.

Comment: I just did it and the LocalTime is exactly the same as after the `add()`, so, what is expected to be in the `ArrayList`. Thanks for the sugestion

Comment: @Skwead `add` doesn't alter the element: [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l442). Mutation of objects after being put into the list and adding the same element repeatedly is the only explanation I can see here.

Comment: I know it doesn't, I read the docs, but logically it's what I see that is happening. Right before I add it I printed it, the value is the one I desired. Right after adding it I get it from the table, wich is different. There is no way I could change it before I printed it and after I added it, since there is no code between the `add()` and the iteration. It's logical to assum the problem is related to the ArrayList itself and the way it handles the `add()` method, since it is where the change occours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three unexplained occurrences are:

```
clock: 22:00
Event exists.
Added event e at 22:00
clock: 22:30
Event exists.
Added event e at 22:30
clock: 23:00
Event exists.
Added event e at 23:00
```

as you can see on your console: for those three events you entered the `if` statement (since there was printed "Event exists.".).

```
if(existsEvent(clock)){
  System.out.println("Event exists.");
  ret = getEvent(clock);
  ret.setLocalDateTime(clock);
}
```

I can only guess what the used functions are doing, but i assume that `existsEvent(clock)` returns true if there exists an `SkEvent` with the same time and date specifiers as `clock` (actual date) (this is obviously true for the three stated cases above). `getEvent(clock)` then retrieves this `SkEvent` and overrides the `ret` variable with it. `ret` is then changed (`ret.setLocalDateTime(clock)`).

`tableToday.add(ret)` does add a **reference** (pointing to the `SkEvent`) to the list. This means, changing the `SkEvent` object afterwards, will also change its *occurrence on the list*, since it is only a pointer pointing to the actual (now altered) object.

What you do here is adding a reference referring to a new object to the list, then (3 times) retrieving it, changing it, and adding an additional reference to the **same** object to this list again.

Comment: It was that, when I called `setTime()` I did not use it on the reference but in the event itself, changing it's `time` to the end time. I solved it by returning a copy of the event instead of the event itself, thank you :) (You would get an upvote if I had the reputation required)